# Combined split plot across environments( locations or years) in R

Tags: r

Dear R users and Programmers;
I have to combine three split-plot experiments conducted in three different locations across two years. can any of you show me how to do that or refer to book or website in which I can get some help.

thank you in advance for your time and help
Hema

Comment: This may not be the forum for this type of question as there is no coding problem described in the question. However, you may get answer for this question on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: make sure to explain what you intend to do with the split plot experiment. Do you consider location variable as nuisance factor, so it can be used as a blocking factor before conducting the experiment or perform ANCOVA if the experiment had been done already, and many more questions like this...